How do I activate the moving blocks?

There is a yellow/gold pedestal (circled) that I've seen at another spot which I assume is what activates the moving blocks. I'd like to loot the chest that is locked behind a gate that is opened by pressing the two buttons. But to get to the buttons, I need to move the blocks out of the way.
How?

There was an item that I needed before I could use the pedestals:

 The Wheel
 Like a hamster wheel, that the ostrich was in, I could activate the pedestals to move the blocks.

 You get this by helping free the 5 bobcats in the ostrich's lair. There are tunes you need to play on the flute to free them. What to play is found throughout the world.

Detailed instructions on how to obtain the item can be found here (too much detail to document here right now):
https://techraptor.net/gaming/guides/animal-well-all-item-locations
